# Why are the d3 stroke styles I have set showing as an empty string in the debugger but red on screen? How do I access the stroke style?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a force-directed graph with multiple `black` coloured graph nodes and some `red` ones. My code is supposed to turn the node's stroke colour to `#2291b97a` when I click on a node but leave the ones that are `red` and `black` as they are.

I turn my nodes `red` based on certain conditions like this:

```
d3.select("svg").selectAll("g.node").each(function(d) {
            if(d == bpOperation) {
                this.firstChild.style = "stroke: red; stroke-width: 3"; 
                }
            });
```

My code changes the colour of the clicked node to #2291b97a, but turns the rest of the nodes' border to `black` -  even the `red` ones.

```
svg.selectAll('g.node')
.every(element => element
        .every(g => (g.firstChild.classList.contains('on')) ? g.firstChild.classList.remove("on") : "true"));


//add on class   
this.firstChild.classList.add("on");

//if it contains an on class set colour to #2291b97a else check if the 
//stroke is red
svg.selectAll('g.node')
.every(element => element
        .every(g => (g.firstChild.classList.contains('on')) ? this.firstChild.style = "stroke: #2291b97a; stroke-width: 3" : ((g.firstChild.style = "stroke: red; stroke-width: 3"==true) ? g.firstChild.style = "stroke: red; stroke-width: 3" : g.firstChild.style = "stroke: black; stroke-width: 2")));
```

In this line I check if the style is set to `red`. If it is `red`, I set it to `red` again otherwise if it isn't I set it to `black`

`((g.firstChild.style = "stroke: red; stroke-width: 3"==true) ? g.firstChild.style = "stroke: red; stroke-width: 3" : g.firstChild.style = "stroke: black; stroke-width: 2"));`

For some reason this statement `(g.firstChild.style = "stroke: red; stroke-width: 3"==true)` always returns false and when I checked what was being actually saved in debug mode I saw that the stroke style for the `red` coloured node was an empty string "" **even though on screen I can see it red**.

So how do I access the stroke property I had changed? Am I even changing the colour correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was applying an inline style and it was showing an empty string in the attributes list because I never set it in the first place.

I had to replace this line

```
this.firstChild.style = "stroke: red; stroke-width: 3";
```

with this line

```
this.firstChild.setAttribute('style','stroke: red; stroke-width: 3;');
```

and likewise get the attributes in the other function like this

```
(g.firstChild.getAttribute('style') == "stroke: red; stroke-width: 3;")
```